# Why does TemplateApply create two identical notebook objects?

Tags: bugs, templates

**Bug introduced in 10.1 or earlier and fixed in 10.4**

 `TemplateApply` is new in 10.0

---

If you start a fresh *Mathematica* session (front end and all), and run the following

```
report=TemplateApply[
File["ExampleData/BasicTemplate.nb"], <|"author" -> "Sarah Miles"|>];
SetOptions[Notebooks["Untitled-2"][[1]], Visible -> True]
SetOptions[Notebooks["Untitled-3"][[1]], Visible -> True]
```

you will see that two identical notebook objects are created. (The one returned by `TemplateApply` to `report` is the second, here `"Untitled-3"`.) Is there a good reason why `TemplateApply` creates two reports?

Comment: It looks like this was a minor bug in 10.3, 10.2, and 10.1. It appears to be fixed in 10.4 though.